# Preparing for Rails deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, macos

Getting ready to deploy a rails project on Mac OS X Leopard Server (such that it matters).

Got a few questions for someone with Rails experience:

- where should directory containing the project go? inside the website's root folder or out?
- who should "own" that directory? www? root? something/someone else?
- hope to continue serving static pages via Apache... would like rails app to be served by mydomain/xxx/railsapp. is there a standard naming convention for 'xxx'?

not expecting too much traffic to begin with...just like to keep things as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Capistrano](http://www.capify.org) for deployment. FAQs and tutorials on the website will make most of your questions fall away.

For running the site, I recommend [Phusion Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/). There's a Capistrano recipe for Passenger [here](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide.html#capistrano).